# execute('tsql_string') inside stored procedure - what permissions/user is used for execute()?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure where I'd like to save the execution of an update statement for further down in the procedure, which I'm doing by putting the sql into a varchar variable.
My problem is that the EXECUTE() seems to use the original caller's permissions and then gives an error, as the caller does not (and should not) have UPDATE permissions for table1.

Why doesn't it use the permissions of the stored procedure's owner?
And more importantly: how can I make it use those permissions?

The stored procedure looks basically like this: (except @tsql_string is set dynamically)

```
create procedure dbo.woopwoop() as
BEGIN
    DECLARE @tsql_string varchar(max)
    SET @tsql_string = 'UPDATE table1 set c1 = 1'

    EXECUTE(@tsql_string)
END
```

I'm on SQL Server 2008, and the owner (me) of the stored procedure is a Windows Authentication user with domain\user.

Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what the [`EXECUTE AS` clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354.aspx) exists for - to allow you to control this:

> By specifying the context in which the module is executed, you can control which user account the Database Engine uses to validate permissions on objects that are referenced by the module.
>
> CALLER
>
> Specifies the statements inside the module are executed in the context of the caller of the module. The user executing the module must have appropriate permissions not only on the module itself, but also on any database objects that are referenced by the module.
>
> CALLER is the default for all modules except queues

You would be wanting to specify that the stored procedure executes as `OWNER` (or possibly `SELF`, read the above page and decide which makes most sense for you) instead.

```
create procedure dbo.woopwoop()
with execute as owner
as
    ....
```

Comment: Thank you! I kept trying to define 'execute as' for the EXECUTE(@tsql_string), I didn't think to define it for the entire procedure.
But I actually thought that stored procedures by default executed their body as the owner...

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN (This example grants `EXECUTE` permission on the stored procedure HumanResources.uspUpdateEmployeeHireInfo to an application role named Recruiting11):

```
USE AdventureWorks2012; 
GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::HumanResources.uspUpdateEmployeeHireInfo
    TO Recruiting11;
GO
```

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345484.aspx)

Of course you should have permission to grant the permission.

Comment: Since the OP specifies "... the caller does not (*and should not*) have UPDATE permissions..." (My *emphasis*) I'm not sure how an answer involving changing permissions can be correct.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, my understanding is, this will will only change permissions of the user for this specific procedure, and will not affect the update permission of the user. I may be wrong (if so, please let me know). Your solution is more elegant anyway :P